# WiFi Driver for old Toshiba

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, toshiba-laptop

I recently reinstalled the windows 7 operating system for my old Toshiba laptop. I cant find the driver for WiFi Adapter.

I don't know exactly the made details. My laptop model is Toshiba Satellite C660, Part No is `PSC0SG-00Q00L`. Seems like model doesn't come with WiFi hardware. But I used WiFi previously and there is label on battery holder, mentioned 'WiFi Certified' with some code - `PA3829U IMPC`.

I tried to find the software using few keywords and the code. but the pages directing to Intel's 404 page. (Seems like, they've permanently stopped supporting)

Kindly anyone please help me on driver software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search on the Toshiba support website suggests that there may be two Wireless LAN cards that may have been installed in your laptop, a Realtek or an Atheros card.

The support website can be found [here](http://www.toshiba.co.uk/innovation/windows7_drivers.jsp?macId=&LNG=1&mode=allMachines&userOS=&action=search&selCategory=2&selFamily=2&selSeries=312&selProduct=6013&selShortMod=-1&selOS=30&selType=97&country=8&language=13&search=) with the best matching search for your drivers, confusingly there is no short model no for `PSC0SG-00Q00L`.

Your best approach would be to take the latest version of the Realtek and Atheros drivers and install them. Should one not work, uninstall and try the other.

Alternatively, if you have a working ethernet connection on your laptop you could try connecting to your router (presuming you have one) via ethernet lead and let Windows 7 update detect and install the correct driver.

Comment: I've tried from referring page already. But it doesnt work. the problem is the downloaded package is extracting, asking administrator permission and happens nothing.

Comment: Also I found the Short model no. from the label bottom of my laptop. I'm sure about it.

Comment: On further investigation it seems as if that laptop is an Indian variant. Forums suggest that the [Toshiba India support page](http://drivers.toshiba-india.com/drivers.aspx?product=Laptop&series=Satellite&model=C660&cat=Wireless+LAN&os=Windows+7+32%2f64+Bit) will provide the correct drivers. Confusingly it looks as if your laptop could also contain a Broadcom card instead.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on ethernet lead?

Comment: I'm giving windows update using wired LAN. will it fix it?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I updated windows and driver has installed. its worked :)

Comment: Great! For clarification Ethernet lead is Wired LAN :)